# Voronoi nerve overlay

Tags: mesh

I'm sorry I deleted my previous post by mistake when I was trying to edit it.
Here is my question again:

I have an image to which I have created a Voronoid mesh using "pts = ImageKeypoints[image]. 
Then I found the Voronoi "nerve" but when I attempt to overlay the nerve over the image using "Show[imge,nerve]th image doesn't appear. 
How can I overlay them?
I'm not sure how to add the image, so I replaced it with the URL. and here is the code:

```
image= Import["https://i.imgur.com/KjcLVlO.jpg"];
maxfeatures = 250;
imgsize = 300;
pts = ImageKeypoints[image, MaxFeatures -> maxfeatures];
vm = VoronoiMesh[pts];
graph = With[{m = DelaunayMesh[pts]}, 
   Graph[MeshCoordinates[m], 
    MeshCells[m, 1] /. Line[{start_, end_}] -> {start, end}, 
    VertexCoordinates -> MeshCoordinates[m], 
    GraphLayout -> "PlanarEmbedding", 
    EdgeStyle -> Directive[Opacity@.5, Dashed, Orange], 
    VertexStyle -> Black, VertexSize -> 5]];
fromLabel[vm_, labels_] := Ordering[Length /@ vm["Faces"]][[labels]]
toLabel[vm_, indices_] := 
 ReplaceAll[indices, 
  Thread[Ordering[Length /@ vm["Faces"]] -> 
    Range[Length[vm["Faces"]]]]]

highlightAdjacentFaces[vm_, label_] := 
 HighlightMesh[vm, 
  Thread[{2, 
    toLabel[vm, vm["FaceFaceConnectivity"][[fromLabel[vm, label]]]]}]]
highestdeg = 
  Flatten@Position[VertexDegree[graph], VertexDegree[graph] // Max];

pts = ImageKeypoints[image, MaxFeatures -> maxfeatures];
vm = VoronoiMesh[pts];
highlightAdjacentFaces[vm, highestdeg]
```

Comment: Your post is utterly incomplete. What is `graph`?

Comment: My apologies. I fixed the code (it's mostly from this forum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just do Show[{image, vm}], vm will override image.   You could set opacity in vm or remove faces:

```
Show[{HighlightImage[image, Style[pts, {AbsolutePointSize[3], 
     Orange}]], 
  MeshRegion[vm, PlotTheme -> "Lines", 
   MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> Directive[Thickness[.002], GrayLevel[.7]]}]
  }]
```

with highlight:

```
Show[{HighlightImage[image, Style[pts, {AbsolutePointSize[3], 
     Orange}]], 
  MeshRegion[highlightAdjacentFaces[vm, highestdeg], 
   PlotTheme -> "Lines", 
   MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> Directive[Thickness[.002], GrayLevel[.7]]}, 
   BaseStyle -> Opacity[.8]]
  }]
```